# Open a shell in the second process of a pipe

Tags: shell, pipe, freebsd

I'm having problems understanding what's going on in the following situation. I'm not familiar with UNIX pipes and UNIX at all but have read documentation and still can't understand this behaviour.

`./shellcode` is an executable that successfully opens a shell:

```
seclab$ ./shellcode
$ exit
seclab$
```

Now imagine that I need to pass data to `./shellcode` via `stdin`, because this reads some string from the console and then prints "hello " plus that string. I do it in the following way (using a **pipe**) and the read and write works:

```
seclab$ printf "world" | ./shellcode
seclab$ hello world
seclab$
```

However, a new shell is not opened (or at least I can't see it and iteract with it), and if I run `exit` I'm out of the system, so I'm not in a new shell.

Can someone give some advice on how to solve this? I need to use printf because I need to input binary data to the second process and I can do it like this: `printf "\x01\x02..."`

Comment: I'm puzzled about what that `shellcode` gizmo is up to.  From your description, when you type `exit`, it should say `hello exit`.  Is `shellcode` your program?  Do you have the source for it?

Comment: As I said `shellcode` is a program that opens a shell. When I type `exit` I exit the opened shell. In the second example, `shellcode` is a program that outputs some string based on some input string, and then opens a shell. I can't modify `shellcode`. The matter is a little bit complicated to explain but I think @Jim Stewart correctly understood it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a pipe, you are telling Unix that the output of the command before the pipe should be used as the input to the command after the pipe.  This replaces the default output (screen) and default input (keyboard).  Your `shellcode` command doesn't really know or care where its input is coming from.  It just reads the input until it reaches the EOF (end of file).

Try running `shellcode` and pressing Control-D.  That will also exit the shell, because Control-D sends an EOF (your shell might be configured to say "type `exit` to quit", but it's still responding to the EOF).

There are two solutions you can use:

**Solution 1:**

Have `shellcode` accept command-line arguments:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Arguments: $*"
exec sh
```

Running:

```
outer$ ./shellcode foo
Arguments: foo
$ echo "inner shell"
inner shell
$ exit
outer$
```

To feed the argument in from another program, instead of using a pipe, you could:

```
$ ./shellcode `echo "something"`
```

This is probably the best approach, unless you need to pass in multi-line data.  In that case, you may want to pass in a filename on the command line and read it that way.

**Solution 2:**

Have `shellcode` explicitly redirect its input from the terminal after it's processed your piped input:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read input; do
  echo "Input: $input"
done
exec sh </dev/tty
```

Running:

```
outer$ echo "something" | ./shellcode
Input: something
$ echo "inner shell"
inner shell
$ exit
outer$
```

If you see an error like this after exiting the inner shell:

```
sh: 1: Cannot set tty process group (No such process)
```

Then try changing the last line to:

```
exec bash -i </dev/tty
```

Comment: I can't modify `shellcode`. In the second solution, what exactly do I have to do? If I create a text file with that content and then run it, I just get a blank console (no $ symbol) and no commands work, so can't progress to the "Running" section.

Comment: Try this: `(printf "world"; cat -) | ./shellcode`.  That will combine your printf output and anything you type after it into a single input stream for shellcode.

Comment: Marked as answer because of your last comment